# My task bar is glitching after latest windows update?

Tags: windows, windows-update, windows-11

Hi my task bar on my laptop after latest update with Windows 11 have wierd stripes every time I boot it up. The stripes over task bar have tendency to disappear after like 20 - 30 minutes. But they appear every single time after boot up my laptop. Current version of my Windows 11 is -  Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1555]. What does is making this problem and how can I fix it? Problem looks like this [image: Stripes on my taskbar after Windows update]

**EDIT** I found out source of my problem. Source of this flickering of task bar is when I had my ****refresh rate** set to 144Hz it was flickering** but **when I switched it into 60Hz flickering magicaly stopped**. I found out that many users encountered this problems month or 2 after their laptop warranty ended.

Comment: Try running DISM / SFC (initial Windows repair).  ........ (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to partialy solve my problem. It turns out that multiple users issued same probelm 1 or 2 months after their laptop warranty ended. I **partialy fixed** it by **switch my refresh rate to 60Hz** from default 144 Hz.

Comment: A partial fix is (a) not as good as what I gave you and (b) little use to most people.

Comment: Yeah but it worked. I tried everything including reinstall my windows and back up my files but sadly it didn't work for me. So maybe it is hardware problem as has been suggested to me .. But anyway thank you for your help :)

Comment: @John Hello I updated my post because I found out where source of that problem was. If you are interested please check it out.

Comment: All my refresh rates are monitor default and i expect most of us do this.

Comment: @John I wanted to say that I never ever switched my refresh rate before. It just started to act wierd and I was trying to figure out why. I even brought my notebook to repair centre even they didn't know source of that problem they suggested me to replace old screen with new one. If you know something more specific about it or about source of that problem you are free to add something new. I honestly don't know what was exact source of that problem I only found out if I switch my refresh rate from default 144Hz to 60 stripes stopped to appear. But idk why sudennly it started acting wierd.

Answer (score 1):

> Task bar is glitching after update

This is not normal the vast majority of the time.

Try running DISM / SFC (initial Windows repair):

(1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.

(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup

(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth

(4) SFC /SCANNOW

(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

This is a good starting point to try.

=================

For additional repairs, use the Windows 11 Repair Install

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

Windows 11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Download.

Run the downloaded file  (double click on it).  You will need a USB key as running the download creates a USB Key.
Run Setup on the USB Key. This will launch the Repair.
Proceed normally answering the prompts.

The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.

If this should fail, the remaining step is to back up and reinstall Windows 11.

There also may be a hardware issue with the video chip if nothing fixes the issue properly.

I think overall, this is a very solid answer.

Comment: After todays booting up of my laptop I realized the pronlem still persist. So where might be a problem then?

Comment: I added steps to my answer for a Windows 11 Repair Install which is the step after DISM and SFC

Comment: Hi I set up my Windows via USB as you recommended but task bar is black and glitchy again. It is sometimes glitichin nearly to half of my screen. I am sure it is not mechanicaly  damaged. So how can I fix it without loosing all my files? I it possible it is related to some kind of virus that I unintentionaly downloaded?

Comment: Back up al your data (make sure ALL) and then follow the last point in my answer above - do a fresh install of Windows 11, add Apps carefully (only the newest versions) and make sure not glitches, then restore your data.

Comment: Hi I managed to fix my problem with downgrading my refresh rate